# Convert float to uint8 buffer

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, uint8t

A have a `float` variable, and I need it's value to be stored in a `uint8` buffer as characters. To be more exact, given something like this

```
float f = 123.45
uint8_t buffer[11];
memset(buffer, 0x30, sizeof(buffer));   // I set it at 0x30 because it is character '0'
```

Given this example, my buffer needs to get the values:

```
0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x2E 0x34 0x35   // 0x2E is the character '.'
```

I unfortunately need it this way to integrate it with a existing functionality, so there is no way around the size `11` buffer.

Any suggestion on how to go about this would be appreciated.

Comment: The decimal text representation of a float can be obtained using the `*printf` family of functions, such as `snprintf`

Comment: *I set it at 0x30 because it is character '0'*  No, it's not.  The character `'0'` is the character `'0'`.  All using `0x30` does is make things confusing.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, They were explaining why `0x30` was being used over `0`. /// @andrei filip, What Andrew is saying is that `'0'` is a lot clearer and 100% equivalent to `0x30` (well, unless you're on an EBCDIC system).

Comment: Given that this is an embedded system and therefore likely resource-constrained, you can't use `stdio.h` functions. Depending on whether your MCU actually has a FPU or not, it may not make sense to use floating point in the first place. So what system is this for, more specifically?

Comment: I am using a STM32L071xB. I have a external device that gives data to my MCU in floating point, then i have to pass it on to another device that has the functionality that requires me to use the uint8_t buffer[11];

Comment: @andreifilip Okay, it's fairly constrained Cortex M0+ then. You shouldn't be using software floating point or `stdio.h` functions on that MCU, they'll eat all your memory. Please trust me on this over random PC programmers on SO. I'm using the very same MCU myself right now and I've got some 20 years of embedded systems programming experience. Instead consider treating the float as raw binary and then parse out integral & fractional parts, store in two ints, convert those to ASCII individually. That's somewhere around 100 times more effective than software floating point and stdio.h.

Comment: Parsing as integral and fractal parts sounds like a good plan, i'll try to do it that way insted.

Comment: The key here is to avoid linking software floating point libs to your project, if possible. Though it is likely that `modff` etc functions from math.h are nicely optimized. `modff` + rolling out a manual "`itoa`" function might be the way to go. Check how much memory each function takes in your .map file. Then compare with stdio.h etc.

Comment: @Lundin [so true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66100025/convert-float-to-uint8-buffer/66100127#comment116865214_66100025)

Comment: A solution without `stdio.h` is practical when `f` has limited range and precision.  andrei filip, what is the smallest (like -123.45), and largest values to convert (e.g. 123456.789)  What precision is needed (e.g. 5 significant digits)?

Comment: it won't get below 0, and at max 99999.99

Comment: I split the float into 2 (fractal and integral) then converted them both to int (cast). Then just made them both hex buffers, and composed a bigger buffer from those two parts. Works well. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is:

1. Allocate buffer with one more element (`buffer_buffer` here)
2. Convert the float to string via [`snprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)
3. Copy the conversion result to `buffer`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
    float f = 123.45;
    uint8_t buffer[11];
    char buffer_buffer[12];
    snprintf(buffer_buffer, sizeof(buffer_buffer), "%011.2f", f);
    memcpy(buffer, buffer_buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) printf(" 0x%02X", buffer[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Directly using `snprintf()` to `buffer` won't work well because there are no room for terminating null-character there.

Comment: This is a PC solution however. `stdio.h` is typically never used in (low-end) embedded systems.

Comment: `"%011.2f"` will have trouble with negative numbers and large positive ones.

Answer (score 0):

> I need it's value to be stored in a uint8 buffer as characters.

Use `sprintf()` and friends to convert the `float` to a string.

The trick is format selection.  How to accommodate the range and precision of a `float` in 11 bytes?

`"%f"` fails for large values.  For small values, information is lost as all becomes "0.0"`.

`"%e"` or `"%g"` solves the range issue with **`"% .3E"`** as that prints `sd.dddEsee\0"`, yet can lose  precision which may need more (e.g. up to 9 significant digits for common `float`).

`"%a"` solves the range issue with `"% .3A"` as that prints `0Xsx.xxxPsbb\0`, is a little better (if the leading "0X" can be discarded) as hexadecimal digits carry more info, yet the exponent may intrude on 3 digits.

---

An adaptive solution.  Try various precessions and return the best available.  `snprintf()` will return [1...10] on success for an 11 byte buffer.

```
 char *print_float(size_t sz, char buffer[sz], float f) {
   for (int p = sz - 1; p >= 0; p--)
     int length = snprintf(buffer, sz, "%.*g", p, f);
     if (length > 0 && (unsigned) length < size) {
       return buffer;
     }
   }
   buffer[0] = 0;
   return buffer;
}
```